# Using the same Hibernate sessionFactory on all requests on Apache Tomcat 6

Tags: java, apache, hibernate, rest, tomcat

I'm trying to understand how [Apache Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) worksm, and I so far believe that it's creating another instance of my application for every request. That's what I get from this line:

```
result = m.invoke(cls.newInstance(), parameters);
```

in the `RestfulTools.java`.

I'm using [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) in my application and getting the Hibernate session from another [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) class with methods related to session management.

Is it possible that all these instances created per request use the same `sessionFactory` for getting the session?

Comment: Typically, an application uses one SessionFactory per dataSource.  But really it depends on how you create and use them.  Are you experiencing a particular problem with your Sessions?

Comment: i have a class full of functions , web services . and if a new instance is created for each request , it means a new sessionfactory for each request , which is very expensive. So if there's a way to use the session factory for all requests (i try to read all docs and things in apache tomcat and i believe thats not the situation right now ) it would save a lot and would be a great performance gain for me

Comment: It's my understanding that Tomcat will only create 1 instance of a servlet by default.  But I am not sure how you are implementing your app/web service.  If you are sure you are getting multiple instances - you should remove the creation of the SessionFactory to somewhere external and inject it where you need it.  Without more implementation details though, it's hard to say more.